# After giving client expire date middleware validation return redirect to dashboard not working properly

Tags: laravel

1. I have created a middleware, the middleware name is expireDateCheck
2. This middleware class I have kept to Kernel.php and I've added to this class protected $routeMiddleware.

**Inside Kernel.php code is:**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [    'expireDateCheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\expireDateCheck::class, ]
```

3. Then I've given a condition inside middleware expireDateCheck.php for redirecting to the dashboard, this condition working fine but the main problem is it's redirecting to the dashboard two times which means after showing dashboard then it's showing again dashboard page it seems like dashboard page loading multiple time.

**How can I fix this problem?**

**Inside middleware expireDateCheck.php code is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use App\Client;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class expireDateCheck
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()){
            $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $userExpireDate = Client::where('expire_date', '<' , $currentDate)->first();
            
            if($userExpireDate){
                return Redirect::to('dashboard');
            }
            
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here are my routes:**@Nikolay

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'expireDateCheck'],function(){ 
    -------------------------------
    -------------------------------
});

Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->middleware('admin');
```

Comment: can you add your routes to post?

Comment: @Nikolay Yes, I can.

Answer (score 0):

The middleware is run on all urls, therefor also on the request when loading the dashboard. You can remove the middlewares when defining the routes, this will avoid it from loading twice, and since the logic is to return them to the dashboard it does not makes sense running it on the dashboard.

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->withoutMiddleware(['expireDateCheck']);
```

Or by grouping multiple.

```
Route::group([
    'excluded_middleware' => ['expireDateCheck'],
], function () {});
```

Comment: I've kept a separate dashboard route from the middleware grouping route but this problem is happening again, I can't solve this issue.